# In chat, links surrounded in square brackets are rendered incorrectly

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

In chat, when you surround a link in square brackets (`[ ]`), the left square bracket gets rendered as part of the link, while the right bracket does not:

```
[[Test](http://google.com/)]
```

produces [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34028980#34028980):

[image]

However, on the main sites, the above markdown renders as expected:

> [[Test](http://google.com/)]

By the looks of it, the markdown rendering engine for chat is greedy, whereas the rendering engine for the main sites is more conservative (like it should be). Hence, the chat markdown engine should be updated to match the functionality of the main markdown engine.

Comment: Work-around until bug solved: `\[[test](http://google.com)]`